# Angularjs - can partials have their own controllers, directives and so on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for ways in angularjs to load partials (HTML templates) into designated divs on a single page. I am interested to try angular ui ... https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router ... I also discovered a few other ways in which I could accomplish visually similar effects.. most interesting of which is this one.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9COtsDovNpM ... In my case I will have to implement both tabs/buttons/menu AND belonging partials dynamically,, loading data from scopes..

I have 3 questions..

1. Can partials (loaded HTML templates) have their own angularjs apps, modules, controllers and other angular components?
2. If answer to 1. is yes,,, are there any special considerations or problems that this aproach creates for development?
3. Are you aware of any simple to follow examples of basic implementation of this idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Actually that's the exact way how things should be done. Define some routes, create a controller and a view for each and glue them together

Comment: Would you say that using angular UI is ok?.. Or development using pure Ng is better? I am curious which off the methods I found is "better".

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't give you an opinion on this as i am personally using the standard routing service. However, i can tell you that it's working very good for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the use of a AMD loader such as RequireJS, it is not possible to create AngularJS apps inside a partials.  The problem is that AngularJS bootstrap itself on a HTML element and definition of a partials is that it get loaded after bootstrapping.

Assuming that your objective is to load controllers, directives, etc only when a partial loads, RequireJS can do that without the need to create a separate app.  Take a look at the sample website below:

http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/

Open your developer tool on your browser and monitor the files being loaded.  You will see that controllers and directives are being loaded when you switch tab for the first time.  Here is a plunker showing how to integrate `angularAMD` with `ui-router`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/czs2G7qHmksiZAmILOcx?p=preview

If you must have separate AngularJS apps, here is a plunker to illustrate how you can create multiple apps in a single page:

http://plnkr.co/edit/R2jVeAWAHTvgoGJX12QE?p=preview

You might still have to bootstrap your "app inside a partials" to an HTML element in your `index.html` but it will be close to what you are looking to do.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I'll go over your suggestions and test out these approaches. I came across a vague article mentioning this but your explanation is much better and clearer.